# How to evaluate $ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx $?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, summation, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

How to evaluate the following integral?
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} dx .$$
I have expanded the numerator using Maclaurin series and the result is
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \frac{x^4}{4}+\ldots}{x}dx. $$
And I have found out that it is $ \pi^2/12 $. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah that's right

Comment: Yes, that is correct.